# Multiple Documents and recipients - soap format issues

Tags: soap, docusignapi

I have to send 2 documents to 2 recipients via DocuSign soap api. 1st document should be signed by the 1st recipient, and then it should go to 2nd recipient to sign the 2nd document.

But when I send using the below soap format, the 1st recipient is prompted to sign on both documents, instead of just the 1st one. 2nd recipient is similarly messed up. Can you please advice what is wrong with this soap structure, or if I am missing any other elements?

Thanks

**Soap format:**

```
            <ns0:Documents>
                <ns0:Document>
                    <ns0:ID>1</ns0:ID>
                    <ns0:Name>TestDocuSign.pdf</ns0:Name>
                    <ns0:PDFBytes xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include">bytes1</ns0:PDFBytes>
                    <ns0:TransformPdfFields>false</ns0:TransformPdfFields>
                    <ns0:FileExtension>pdf</ns0:FileExtension>
                    <ns0:AttachmentDescription>DS1</ns0:AttachmentDescription>
                </ns0:Document>
                <ns0:Document>
                    <ns0:ID>2</ns0:ID>
                    <ns0:Name>TestDocuSign2.pdf</ns0:Name>
                    <ns0:PDFBytes xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include">bytes2</ns0:PDFBytes>
                    <ns0:TransformPdfFields>false</ns0:TransformPdfFields>
                    <ns0:FileExtension>pdf</ns0:FileExtension>
                    <ns0:AttachmentDescription>DS2</ns0:AttachmentDescription>
                </ns0:Document>
            <ns0:Recipients>
                <ns0:Recipient>
                    <ns0:ID>1</ns0:ID>
                    <ns0:UserName>abc</ns0:UserName>
                    <ns0:SignerName>abcName</ns0:SignerName>
                    <ns0:Email>abc@yhoo.com</ns0:Email>
                    <ns0:Type>Signer</ns0:Type>
                    <ns0:AccessCode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns0:RoutingOrder>1</ns0:RoutingOrder>
                </ns0:Recipient>
                <ns0:Recipient>
                    <ns0:ID>2</ns0:ID>
                    <ns0:UserName>def</ns0:UserName>
                    <ns0:SignerName>defName</ns0:SignerName>
                    <ns0:Email>def@yhoo.com</ns0:Email>
                    <ns0:Type>Signer</ns0:Type>
                    <ns0:AccessCode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <ns0:RoutingOrder>2</ns0:RoutingOrder>
                </ns0:Recipient>
            </ns0:Recipients>
            <ns0:Tabs>
                <ns0:Tab>
                    <ns0:DocumentID>1</ns0:DocumentID>
                    <ns0:RecipientID>1</ns0:RecipientID>
                        <ns0:AnchorTabItem>
                            <ns0:AnchorTabString>SIGNATURE</ns0:AnchorTabString>
                            <ns0:XOffset>0.0</ns0:XOffset>
                            <ns0:YOffset>-10.0</ns0:YOffset>
                            <ns0:Unit>Pixels</ns0:Unit>
                            <ns0:IgnoreIfNotPresent>true</ns0:IgnoreIfNotPresent>
                        </ns0:AnchorTabItem>
                    <ns0:Type>SignHere</ns0:Type>
                </ns0:Tab>
                <ns0:Tab>
                    <ns0:DocumentID>2</ns0:DocumentID>
                    <ns0:RecipientID>2</ns0:RecipientID>
                        <ns0:AnchorTabItem>
                            <ns0:AnchorTabString>SIGNATURE</ns0:AnchorTabString>
                            <ns0:XOffset>50.0</ns0:XOffset>
                            <ns0:YOffset>-10.0</ns0:YOffset>
                            <ns0:Unit>Pixels</ns0:Unit>
                            <ns0:IgnoreIfNotPresent>true</ns0:IgnoreIfNotPresent>
                        </ns0:AnchorTabItem>
                    <ns0:Type>SignHere</ns0:Type>   
                </ns0:Tab>
            </ns0:Tabs>
```

Comment: This is a common DocuSign new developer issue "anchor" tab text allows multiple tags to be placed on same anchor string. I do understand how it appears to be "soap" related since you see it through that lens and I am happy Amit K Bist was able to help you with an explanation. I think if you search again you will see why most people can't find a solution, it requires to specify a search to find the problem as it is hidden in the way the API was being used and what form. Watch out for "Data in Tabs" as this counts when searching the document. There is a street with "City" in it.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your code, it seems `SIGNATURE` anchorString is available on both documents. `AnchorString` scope is not limited to document level, instead it is at `envelope level`. When you mention AnchorString, DocuSign will search that anchorString in complete envelope, in your case it will find this string in both documents for both the recipients, hence both recipients are seeing Signature Tab on both documents. Solution is to change the Anchor String for both signers, make Signature1 for Signer1 and Signature2 for Signer2, then everything will work fine as Signarure1 will be present in Document1 and Signature2 will be only present in Document2.